# Dynamic mapped property using mapData

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

```
mapData()
```

function inside stylesheet works very nicely but I want to enable/disable/update it dynamicly based on user input. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the selector block match or not match, e.g. by adding or removing a class.